# Can Derived class constructor inherit base class constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I am c beginer to c++ and i found something strange and was not able to understand couldn't find anything on internet so wanted to ask here. The code i saw was this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A 
{
    protected : int a;
    public:
        A(int a) 
        {
            this -> a = a;
        }
    virtual void foo() 
    {
        cout<<"A =" <<a <<endl;
    }
};

class B: public A 
{
    public: B(int b): A(b + 1) {}
    virtual void foo() 
    {
        cout<<"B =" <<a <<endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    A * a = new B(1);
    a -> foo();
    return 0;
}
```

the line that creates problem to me is this `public: B(int b): A(b + 1) {}`in derived class. Where i can obserrve that Derived class inheriting the base class constructor and its output is `B=2`. Could someone please explain me in detail how it became possible ? that in line  A * a = new B(1); here "1" is passed as object and its value gets increased in `A(b + 1) {}` constructor by inheriting from `A class` in line  `public: B(int b): A(b + 1) {}`.

Comment: It's a constructor initializer list.

Comment: @chris sorry could you please explain in detail ?

Comment: I'd be wasting my "breath". It's explained in just about every book, as well as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor).

Comment: @chris Agreed, that's the whole point of marking as duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more detail then necessary, but here we go.

```
A * a = new B(1);
```

This line creates a new B object, passing 1 to its constructor.

```
class B: public A 
{
    public: B(int b): A(b + 1) {}
```

The constructor receives 1, then calls the A base constructor with b + 1 (2)

```
A(int a) 
{
  this -> a = a;
}
```

A's constructor sets `a` to 2.

Because you used the `virtual` keyword on `foo()`, you are saying: "Hey compiler, use dynamic binding for this function call." This means that if `a` is an `A` then `A::foo` will be called. If `a` is a `B` ("hiding" in its base type `A`) then the compiler will call `B::foo`.

```
A * a = new B(1);
```

The fact that a `B` object can live in an `A` object is the concept of "polymorphic objects". The fact that the `virtual` keyword tells the compiler to dispatch the function call to either `A::foo` or `B::foo` is the concept of "dynamic binding" or "functional polymorphism".

```
a -> foo();
```

Here we see dynamic binding in action. B::foo() is called which returns `B = 2`

Comment: thanks for the beauttiful answer. I couldnt understand tthis line, could you please explain it : "This means that if a is an A then A::foo will be called. If a is a B ("hiding" in its base type A) then the compiler will call B::foo"

Comment: and both of the functions are virtual.

Answer (score 1):

This record

```
public: B(int b): A(b + 1) {}
```

does not mean the inheritance of the base constructor.  it means that the base class constructor is called in the mem-initializer list of the derived class constructor.

For example you coudl rewrite constructor of class A

```
    A(int a) 
    {
        this -> a = a;
    }
```

the following way

```
    A(int a) : a( a ) 
    {
    }
```

It does not mean that class A inherites int a. it means that data member a is initialized by parameter a.